# fastapi validation error code

Tags: python, fastapi

В fastapi хочу поменять код для Validation Error. Нашел вот такой способ

```
@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors()}),
    )
```

В ответе будет код 200, но в свагере по прежнему 422.

---

https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2455
Хотя, хотелось бы какой-то более корректный способ